# ShareKit like framework for Mac

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, sharekit

I am looking for a ShareKit like framework for Mac.
Do you know if something similar exists?

Thanks !

Comment: For this kind of question, actually explaining what ShareKit *is* might be useful.

Comment: It's a social sharing framework for iPhone http://www.getsharekit.com/

Comment: I think you have to go to respective services sites (twitter, ecc) in order to search if they have got their own SDKs

Comment: ShareKit is open source, so you could probably just rip out the UI layers and put in your own.

Comment: Dave, I just wanted to know if someone already did it actually ;)

Answer (score 3):

The guts of Sharekit should be very easy to port to Mac. You could then develop a new UI over the top.

Be warned though I do not think that sharekit is being maintained anymore. I do not think it is up to date with the new Facebook and Twitter auth systems and it does not play well with gesture recognisers (not that that'll be an issue on Mac).

Comment: ShareKit is being brought alive, with all up to date new auth systems both for Facebook and Twitter. https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit

Answer (score 1):

Although it has been suggested multiple times on different forums, to the best of my knowledge nobody has posted any details of such a project. Your best bet will be to pick and choose the ones you need to integrate and add them in one at a time, the old fashioned way.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can take a look to TwUi for twitter... http://engineering.twitter.com/2011/07/starting-today-twitter-is-offering-twui.html

Comment: TWui is just for the UI part. It does not manage social sharing at all.